# Can apps created using Quickly for Ubuntu be used in other linux distros?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, canonical-quickly, linux-distro

I need to write a small program to update my mongodb. I'm currently on ubuntu but I need to use it on other linux distributions.

I would just like to make sure that applications using [this method](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/) can be run on other distros.

Is that true ?

Comment: Neat.  I've never seen Quickly before :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes you can

The default quickly template for ubuntu application use [pyGOBJECT](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject) which is available in all modern distros, So you don't have to worry about it. But if used ubuntu specific features like [appindicator](http://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/appindicators/),unity integration etc, You have to make tiny changes in the source code before porting to another distro